# Is there any way to keep my own order when drawing a funnel with jqplot?

Tags: jqplot

As you might knwo the funnel renderer will automatically order the values before drawing the funnel. In my case that's not helpful at all since I'm trying to show sale in each stage.

Is there any way to disable that auto-ordering?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue myself but unfortunately it required me to modify jqplot.funnelRenderer.js by commenting lines 182 and 183:

```
this.data.sort( function (a, b) { return b[1] - a[1]; } );
idxs.sort( function (a, b) { return b[1] - a[1]; });
```

I say unfortunately because i can't predict the ramifications of such a change even though it looks like it works okay at the moment.